# Simple fadeOut/In more complicated than I think it should be?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

This is my first time posting. I use this site a lot and find it very useful in my learning. I am fairly new to JS/jQuery.

Here is my code http://codepen.io/Dawdre/pen/pjZxZj

HTML:

```
<div id="page1" class="col-8">
     <h2 class="row-headers">Music</h2>
    <p class="row-txt">Text here.
        <br>
        <br>Text here
        <br>
        <br>Text here</p>
    <br>
     <h2 class="row-headers">Songs</h2>
    <p class="row-txt">Text here</p>
    <br>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="col-8">
     <h2 class="row-headers">Drama</h2>
    <p class="row-txt">Text here
        <br>
        <br>Text here
        <br>
        <br>Text here</p>
    <br>
     <h2 class="row-headers">Contact</h2>
    <p class="row-txt">Text here</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#banner").hide(0).delay(0).fadeIn(2000);


    $('#pagetop').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
    });

    $('.menu-btn').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.row').offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#next-btn').click(function () {
        $('#page1').fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $('#page2').delay(0).fadeIn(2500);
        });
    });

});
```

The css for 'page2' is

```
#page2 {
    display: none;
}
```

I simply want to fade out the div element 'page1' and fade in div 'page2'. I want be able to transition from content to content seamlessly by clicking either 'menu-btn' or the 'next-btn'. Whilst staying on the same page.
Even with my limited knowledge it seems like a fairly easy thing to do but so far I am being proven wrong!

Is there a better way to do it? I have sampled with hide() and animate(). Set the opacity to 0 and fadeIn, but page1 was just not even disappearing. page2 seems to be reacting well but page1 is not to any sort of jQuery I have tried.

It kind of works...well not really. There seems to be a break in the animation and the upper half of page1 does not completely disappear. Then the fade In for page2 kicks in overlapping page1. Then page1 disappears immediately.

Basically it is far from smooth. It seems broken in some way. Whether it be html, css or JS related, hours of googling and searching on here has not given me the answer.

I feel this is more of a problem with my code specifically than actually how to jQuery. Although I know for sure there would a better way of doing it too as I am still learning. Thanks.

Comment: Where is banner in: ` $("#banner").hide(0).delay(0).fadeIn(2000);`? - for that matter, none of the html matches the javacript

Comment: A div in my HTML: <div id="banner">. Inside is my slideshow. I wanted to fade it in onload smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I created a very basic demo of how to do a fade toggle with CSS and jQuery. I like this method because you can accomplish a lot with CSS without jQuery.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Fade Toggle</button>
<img class="img1" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/326221/dummy.jpg">
<img class="img2" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/326221/animals-q-c-640-480-3.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
.img1, .img2{
   position: absolute;
   transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.hide{
   opacity: 0;
}
```

`transition: all 2s ease-in-out;` this line of CSS is where the magic happens for the fade effect.

JS:

```
$('.btn').on("click", function(){
   $('.img2').toggleClass('hide'); 
});
```

Essentially we are just using a little jQuery to just toggle the elements class.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/OyaGXJ)

Comment: I very much appreciate your time for your response. I am a little confused how I could apply that to text? As positioned absolutely the text sits on top of each other and does not look great. Also forgive me but I am confused where you got .hide from? My code is not affected by that at all. Thanks again.

Comment: I used position absolute because I was using images on top of each other, I created a class of ``.hide`` in CSS to be a helper class (with an opacity of 0), jQuery toggles that class to hide that element and ``transition: all 2s ease-in-out;`` gives it a fade effect.

Comment: I see how it works yes. Thank you. Unfortunately it does not work for me. As I have to hide the text that I want to fade In first. Otherwise its just sitting there on top of the current text on the page.

Comment: I updated my pen to show you how you can apply that technique to text.

Comment: Thankyou for that. I feel a toggle is not what I am after. I am looking to transition to a different div of text with the probability of then transitioning to another div. Also sadly the code does not work for me. In the jQuery i thought the lack of . in toggleClass.(hide); might of been it. But then I noticed yours also does not have a '.hide' just 'hide'

Comment: when you're declaring ``toggleClass`` **don't** add the period just the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to your pages then toggle them with that button click as: (verbose to make it obvious)

```
$('#next-btn').click(function () {
    var notshown = $('.fadepages').filter(":hidden");
    var shown = $('.fadepages').not(":hidden");
    shown.fadeOut(1000, function () {
        notshown.fadeIn(2500);
    });
});
```

SO when you click it again, it fades to the OTHER one.  If you have a large number and want to fade them in sequence, you could find the current one, then get the "next" one unless it is the last then the show the first one...such as:

```
$('#next-btn').click(function () {
    var pgs = $('.fadepages');
    var shown = pgs.not(":hidden");
    var si = pgs.index(shown);
    $('#shownpage').text(si + ":" + pgs.length);
    shown.fadeOut(1000, function () {
        var fadeindex = si < pgs.length - 1 ? si + 1 : 0;
        pgs.eq(fadeindex).fadeIn(2500);
    });
});
$('.fadepages').not(":first").hide();
```

Example page for that last: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/t9L2wnsL/

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to do this. It does work...to a point. I am getting some error with the smoothness of the animation. It doesnt fully fade out until the other page has faded in. The previous page sits there overlapping the text then once the next div has fully faded in the previous text all of a sudden disappears like a light bulb. Now I went back to my original code with the simple fade out fade in callback and it does the same thing. Seems to work fine but there is that strange, what seems to be an animation issue still there. http://jsfiddle.net/dawdre/n6qf1yf4/

Comment: That fiddle does not even have jQuery on it.  It does appear that you might have multiple animations going on at the same time perhaps?

Comment: Ok so. I think your theory on multiple animations could be correct. Although in Firefox it works perfectly. Chrome the fadeout is sticking and disappearing only once other text has faded in. Very strange. Any theories would be appreciated.